# Compress separately files within subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, 7zip, zip, subdirectory

Hi all and thanks for the answers,

Firstly, I tried to find the answer to my problem but I did not find anything.

I have a tree of folders and sub-folders and I want to use 7zip to compress the files within those folders separately.

I have got this piece of code from this very website,  it does what I want to get but it places the compressed files on the main folder:

```
    set extension=.*
    for /R %%a in (*%extension%) do "%sevenzip%" a -mx "%%~na.zip" "%%a"
```

I wonder if I can get a zip file of every file and have it in the sub-folder containing the source file. Or doing the process above and place every zip file inside the appropriate sub-folder.

I tried with a double 'For /d' but I was unable to get it:

```
    cd /d %~dp0

    rem 7z.exe path

    set sevenzip=

    if "%sevenzip%"=="" if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe" set 

    sevenzip=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe


    if "%sevenzip%"=="" if exist "%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe" set 

    sevenzip=%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe


    if "%sevenzip%"=="" echo 7-zip not found&pause&exit

    for /D %%O in (*) do (

        for /R %%I in ("%%O\*") do (
            "%sevenzip%" a -mx "%%~na.zip" "%%a"

            ::        rd /s /q "%%I"  **Because I do not want to delete anything by now.

        )
    )
```

Again, thank you.

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have somewhat complex folder structure then you probably better use plain list from `dir`:

```
  dir /a:-d /s /b /o
```

Just use its output in `for`:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /a:-d /s /b /o') do (
  echo %%f <-- %%f is a full path to a file, do something with it
)
```

Btw, 7zip has useful option `-sdel` to remove the source file when archive has been created successfully.

Comment: Hi, could you be more specific? I do not get what you mean with "Just use its output in for" Which one "For /R" or "For /D"?
Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood your goal a bit. My sample is for compressing individual files; if you want to compress folders you must use `/a:d` parameter. Other things are the same.

Comment: Oh sorry, no no, you're right. I want to compress files and keep the compressed files in the same folder than the non-compressed file.

the thing is I used the piece of code you posted (updated) and It seems that it is scanning the whole c: drive. CODE:

for /f %%I in ('dir /a:-d /s /b /o') do (
@echo %%I
        "%sevenzip%" a -mx -mmt2 "%%I.7z" -r -xr!*.bat "%%I"
        rd /s /q "%%I"
)

Comment: Using `/a:-d` means that you only want to see things that are NOT a directory.  Using `/a:d` means that you only want to see directories.

Comment: @AlejandroSalido `dir` uses current working folder if the path is omitted. To scan specific folder, just specify the path: `dir <params> c:\path\to\folder`. As for your code, I can't realize one thing. If you process files then why you use `rd` on them? This command removes folders. Moreover, there's no need in special remove command as 7zip has "remove source after archiving" mode with `-sdel` option.

Comment: @frost Because I am not working with the a7zip.exe so I cannot use all those commands. If I place -sdel I doesn't work: "Incorrect command line". Moreover, with the 7z.exe that I am using if I place "-x!*.bat" it allows that command but it compresses bat files anyway.

It is a company's laptop so I cannot install the a7zip.exe to use 7zip exclusively with commands.

Comment: @AlejandroSalido `-sdel` option has been introduced recently so you've got to update your 7zip. You don't have to install it, just use self-contained standalone `7za.exe` from the archive. As for exclude option, try to check  your command line syntax. For me this option works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code:

@echo off

cd /d %~dp0

rem 7z.exe path

set sevenzip=

if "%sevenzip%"=="" if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe" set sevenzip=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe

if "%sevenzip%"=="" if exist "%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe" set sevenzip=%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe

if "%sevenzip%"=="" echo 7-zip not found&pause&exit

@echo searching...

```
for /R %%I in (*) do (
    "%sevenzip%" a -mx -mmt4 "%%I.7z" -r -x!*.bat "%%I"
```

)

del "Compressing_files_7zip.bat.7z"*

del *.7z.7z

del *.zip.7z

::::::::::::::::::::::::::For setting up shutdown 60' after the end of the process.Remove colons in the line below.
::shutdown.exe /s /t 3600

pause

Thanks all for the support, especially to Frost.

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler version without using 7zip:

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /a:-d /s /b /o *.mdb') do (
    zip -r -p "%%f.zip" "%%f"
)
```

Comment: The OP states: "I want to use 7zip" - whats the need of posting an answer that does not use 7zip?