# Jump inside a 'FOR' loop within a BATCH file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, delete-file

Time ago I request some help to develope a short batch file to compress files inside a tree using 7zip, see following link:

[Compress separately files within subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083932/compress-separately-files-within-subfolders)

Now I want to avoid already zipped files (.7z, .zip files) and jump to the next item.

Also I want to remove previous compressed files (like '*.7z.7z' or '*.zip.7z') created by using the original batch file several times on a same folder.

This is what I got so far:

```
@echo off
cd /d %~dp0
rem 7z.exe path
set sevenzip=
if "%sevenzip%"=="" if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe" set sevenzip=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\7-zip\7z.exe

if "%sevenzip%"=="" if exist "%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe" set sevenzip=%ProgramFiles%\7-zip\7z.exe

if "%sevenzip%"=="" echo 7-zip not found&pause&exit
@echo searching...
for /R %%I in (*) do (
        if not exist %%I.zip if not exist %%I.7zip "%sevenzip%" a -mx -mmt4 "%%I.7z" -r -x!*.bat "%%I" && "%sevenzip%" t "%%I.7z" * -r

)

del "Compressing_files_7zip.bat.7z"
del *.7z.7z*
del *.zip.7z*

::::::::::::::::::::::::::For setting up shutdown 60' after the end of the process.Remove colons in the line below.
::shutdown.exe /s /t 3600

pause
```

The main issues I get with this code are:

-I am unable to detect already compressed files and therefore, jump to the next %%I entity.

-Remove non-desirable over-zipped files from sub-folders. Obviously, '*' wildcard does not work inside the loop; on the other hand, if I look for 'del %%I.7z.7z' it does not work either.

I read I cannot use a proper 'OR' fuction for the 'if' loops, that is why I nested them.

Thank you in advance.

Alex.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /R %%I in (*) do (
        if not exist %%I.zip if not exist %%I.7zip "%sevenzip%" a -mx -mmt4 "%%I.7z" -r -x!*.bat "%%I" && "%sevenzip%" t "%%I.7z" * -r

)
```

Note that `%%I` will contain the **complete** filename, so if you locate `whatever.zip` then the code looks for whatever.zip**.zip** or whatever.zip**.7zip** and will execute the `7zip` if **both** of these are absent and generate whatever.zip**.7z**

so if you locate `whichever.txt` then the code looks for whichever.txt**.zip** or whichever.txt**.7zip** and will execute the `7zip` if **both** of these are absent and generate whichever.txt**.7z**

I'd suggest

```
for /R %%I in (*) do (
  if not exist %%~nI.zip if not exist %%~nI.7z "%sevenzip%" a -mx -mmt4 "%%~nI.7z" -r -x!*.bat "%%I" && "%sevenzip%" t "%%~nI.7z" * -r

)
```

which should select the `name` part only of the filename. (see `for /?|more` from the prompt for docco)

Hence, the code would look for `whatever.zip` or `whatever.7z` - finds `whatever.zip` and doesn't execute `7zip`

or, for `whichever.txt`, the code would look for `whichever.zip` or `whichever.7z` - finds neither and executes `7zip` generating `whichever.7z`

Now, since `whichever.7z` exists, further runs will skip the `7zip`.

Which raises the question - if the zip/7z exists, why not try to freshen the archive, since the detected file may have changed?

Comment: Thank you Magoo.

The code skips already zipped files but also files with double extension (there might be such files) . Moreover, I guess according to my proposed syntaxis the zipped files are not longer created on the source folder instead they appear where I place the batch file. 

Answering your question: Because it would zip again large files which have not change (if there is a change it would become 'v2' or so) and that is not desirable.

Comment: Let me suggest quoting like `if not exist "%%~nI.zip" if not exist "%%~nI.7z"`...

Comment: @aschipfl TY but I did not get it working. Anyway, I need to work on the file name and then make sure the compression occurs on the source folder.